"No module named numpy" when trying to install eif from pypi with pixi
I am trying to use pixi for a python library, and it's running into an error when trying to install the pipy dependency eif.
~/code> pixi init test-pixi-eif --format pyproject
✔ Created /home/oliver/code/test-pixi-eif/pyproject.toml
~/code/test-pixi-eif> cd test-pixi-eif/
~/code/test-pixi-eif> pixi add numpy
✔ Added numpy >=2.1.3,<3
~/code/test-pixi-eif> pixi add --pypi eif
  × default: error installing/updating PyPI dependencies
  ├─▶ Failed to prepare distributions
  ├─▶ Failed to download and build `eif==2.0.2`
  ╰─▶ Build backend failed to determine requirements with `build_wheel()` (exit status: 1)
      
      [stderr]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
          requires = get_requires_for_build({})
        File "/home/oliver/.cache/rattler/cache/uv-cache/builds-v0/.tmplz6UaX/lib/python3.13/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 334, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/home/oliver/.cache/rattler/cache/uv-cache/builds-v0/.tmplz6UaX/lib/python3.13/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 304, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
        File "/home/oliver/.cache/rattler/cache/uv-cache/builds-v0/.tmplz6UaX/lib/python3.13/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 522, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/home/oliver/.cache/rattler/cache/uv-cache/builds-v0/.tmplz6UaX/lib/python3.13/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 320, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
          ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
          if sys.path[0] == "":
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

The corresponding pyproject.toml file is:
[project]
authors = [{name = "foo", email = "bar"}]
description = "Add a short description here"
name = "test-pixi-eif"
requires-python = ">= 3.11"
version = "0.1.0"
dependencies = ["eif>=2.0.2,<3"]

[build-system]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"
requires = ["hatchling"]

[tool.pixi.project]
channels = ["conda-forge"]
platforms = ["linux-64"]

[tool.pixi.pypi-dependencies]
test_pixi_eif = { path = ".", editable = true }

[tool.pixi.tasks]

[tool.pixi.dependencies]
numpy = ">=2.1.3,<3"

I've also tried having eif under [tool.pixi.pypi-dependencies], and not first installing numpy, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.
What I find puzzling is that when I manually install numpy in a micromamba/conda environment, and then pip install eif, I don't encounter any issues. I thought that pixi is doing essentially the same, but there must be some difference somewhere.
